# How to create an index in word file programmatically?

Tags: plugins, ms-word, swt, ole, docx4j

Suppose there is table of thousand data items and we need to create an index of any of the items.
So,how can an index be created in Docx file programmatically i.e with the help of docx4j.

Comment: You might be better off using Apache POI to read the docx file.

Comment: Or pxDoc... (www.pxdoc.fr)

Comment: Or Visual Basic – i.e., no need for an external programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MainDocumentPart mdp = word.getMainDocumentPart();
        String textXpath = "//w:t";
        List<Object> textNodes= mdp.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(textXpath, true);
        c=0;
        for (Object obj : textNodes)
        {
            Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();       
            textValue = text.getValue();
         String[] words = textValue.split("\\W+");
            for (String word : words) 
            {
             word = word.toLowerCase();
             List<Integer> list = occurences.get(word);

             if (list == null) 
             {
                 list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 occurences.put(word, list);
             }

             list.add(c);
         }

         c++;

        }
        //System.out.print(occurences.toString());
        word.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("");
        word.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("");
        word.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Title", "INDEX");
        String count = occurences.toString();
        word.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("count");
```

Comment: The above code  will count the occurrences of each item in the table and will return the position of each item.